# Memory segmentation

Tags: c++, oop, class, object

I was asked these questions in a interview.

1. Why exactly Binary code and Data was separated i.e why did they plan for Data segment why not everything inside code segment?

2.

```
class A
{
private :
    int i;
public:
    void show()
    {
        printf("hello");
    }
};
int main()
{
    A* a = NULL; (what happens in object table?)
        A* aa =  new A();  (what happens in object table?)

        a->show();
    aa->show();

    delete aa;
    return 0;
}
```

How exactly aa and a are different and how exactly object behaves inside memory.

Comment: What is an object table in this context?

Comment: I guess object table here refers to compiler symbol table?

Comment: Unless you were going for a job on a compiler team I would have asked why it mattered. The compiler would use the optimal solution as defined on a per platform basis.

Comment: I mean to say how will the show function called and where does the address of that function stored ?

Comment: I use to give interviews and I have also been interviewed. Some interviewers what to catch people out - that is unfair and wrong. The whoie point of an interview is not to show off over a person that is looking for a job (that person is nervous and under pressure). Those companies are not worth working for anyway. (This is my rant and my humble opinion)

Comment: >>Those companies are not worth working for anyway ---- I would say it depends, even great companies has someone who is "unreasonable", sometime it is just you are of bad luck run into those person.

Comment: Is it really a bad interview question??? It may be a hard question. Those interviewees that can demonstrate TRUE a passion for inner working knowledge, also tend to have awesome understanding of code intent and architect. It is a bit like the mechanic in a garage that relies on a engine management unit telling hie what is wrong  and what he should do. Whereas another mechanic would know WHY the EMU is telling him that and make a confident decision if the EMU is right or the manufacturer is trying to screw you for more cash with expensive replacements and just fix the affected part!

Comment: In this case the interviewer is probably trying to see if you can quickly see the intent behind the design, i.e. some parts of a system are invariant during the life time of the application and should not change (the code segment) and others are mutable (data).  This is a common theme in any system......
Those that can understand code/design intent very quickly do not have such a steep learning curve when they join a team who are working on very large complex systems (however they might still hate the design!!! :-) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### code segment vs data segment

code segment is read-only, while data segment is read/write, if you mix these 2 sections together, update the data while keep the code secure becomes a challenge: one example is as Lol4t0 pointed out:

> As to the OS memory management, the code segment will be swap out to
> its original executable file on the file system, while the data
> segment, which is deemed to change, are swapped out to paging file. if you mixed them
> together, you may lose the advantage of reusing the executable as paging file.

and also, code segment are usually load into memory pages which are readonly [(VirtualAlloc(PAGE_READONLY)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887(v=vs.85).aspx))

#### a(null) vs aa (non-null)

a and aa themselves are simply stack variable of type A*, but a points to NULL, while aa points to an object allocated in heap.

a->show() is translated into:

```
A_show(a)
//which is:
A_show(NULL)
```

because no member variable is referenced in show(), this should works fine.

aa->show() is translated into:

```
A_show(aa)
```

here aa is a valid address, so even if you reference member variable in show(), it would work.

Notice unlike virtual functions, which is resolved in runtime thus require a vptr in each object, member functions are just normal functions which take the *this* as first parameter, and resolved by compiler in compile time.

Comment: interviewer was not happy with this answer.. i had given him this answer

Answer (score 1):

The other reason to separate code & data is memory management.

When you get low physical memory, you can just 'forget' code page and reread it from disc when you will need it. But you cannot do the same for data. You should move page to swap/page file in this situation. Now if you had mixed code & data pages, you would have to keep them in swap/page, so this strategy saves resources.

<sub>Well, I do not pretend to completeness.</sub>

Comment: Good point! This also boils down to the readonly attribute of the code segment.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the 2nd part is a bit of a trick question.  You would think a segmentation fault would occur, but since `A::show` doesn't reference any data parts of the class, it will be optimized to be part of the binary code (almost like a static method) and you will get "hellohello".  Just change the printf to `printf("hello %d ", i);` and you'll get the segmentation fault.